# Symfony2 PHP header redirect after x seconds

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to do a PHP Header redirect after x seconds in Symfony, something like:

```
    header( "refresh:5;url=http://www.something.com" );
```

how can I do that in Symfony2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony) is must be something like that:

```
$response = new Response();

$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->headers->set('Refresh', '5; url=http://www.something.com/');

$response->send();
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, I tried something similar before but I had an error