# symfony redirects from page to page every couple of seconds

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, twig

I would like to redirect from page index to slide 1 to slide 2 and then to slide 3 every 5 seconds. How can I do that. So far i try this using this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/3.1/components/http_foundation.html#redirecting-the-user

and help from this question:

[How to auto redirect a user in Symfony after a session time out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232587/how-to-auto-redirect-a-user-in-symfony-after-a-session-time-out)

In controller:

```
/**
 * Bisdisp slide show preview action
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @Route("/bisdisp/{id}/slideshow/", name="_get_bisdisp_slideshow", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function slideshowAction($id)
{
    $power_plant = $this->getPowerPlant($id);
    $response = new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('_get_bisdisp_slide1', [ 'id' => $id ]));
    // $response->headers->set('Refresh', 5);

    return $response;
}

/**
 * Slide 1 view
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @Route("/bisdisp/{id}/slideshow/slide1/", name="_get_bisdisp_slide1", requirements={"id" = "\d*"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function slide1Action($id)
{
    $power_plant = $this->getPowerPlant($id);
    $response = new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('_get_bisdisp_slide2', [ 'id' => $id ]));
    // $response->headers->set('Refresh', 5);

    return $response;
}

/**
 * Slide 2 view
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @Route("/bisdisp/{id}/slideshow/slide2/", name="_get_bisdisp_slide2", requirements={"id" = "\d*"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function slide2Action($id)
{
    $power_plant = $this->getPowerPlant($id);
    $response = new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('_get_bisdisp_slide3', [ 'id' => $id ]));
    // $response->headers->set('Refresh', 5);

    return $response;
}
```

into my views:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
{% block content %}
<h3>Slide index</h3>
{% endblock %}

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
{% block content %}
<h3>Slide 1</h3>
{% endblock %}

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
{% block content %}
<h3>Slide 2</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Remove the `http-equiv` in your views and check how you can redirect after some duration in sf http://stackoverflow.com/a/18176467/1507546

Comment: Tnx, It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not refresh page from your views, so you need to remove `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">`.

And then you could do something similar to this:

```
private function getRedirectLater($url, $seconds=5)
{
    $response = new Response;
    $response->headers->set('Refresh', $seconds.'; url='. $url);

    return $response;
}

/**
 * Bisdisp slide show preview action
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @Route("/bisdisp/{id}/slideshow/", name="_get_bisdisp_slideshow", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function slideshowAction($id)
{
    $power_plant = $this->getPowerPlant($id);

    return $this->getRedirectLater($this->generateUrl('_get_bisdisp_slide1', [ 'id' => $id ]));
}

/**
 * Slide 1 view
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @Route("/bisdisp/{id}/slideshow/slide1/", name="_get_bisdisp_slide1", requirements={"id" = "\d*"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function slide1Action($id)
{
    $power_plant = $this->getPowerPlant($id);

    return $this->getRedirectLater($this->generateUrl('_get_bisdisp_slide2', [ 'id' => $id ]));
}

/**
 * Slide 2 view
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @Route("/bisdisp/{id}/slideshow/slide2/", name="_get_bisdisp_slide2", requirements={"id" = "\d*"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function slide2Action($id)
{
    $power_plant = $this->getPowerPlant($id);

    return $this->getRedirectLater($this->generateUrl('_get_bisdisp_slide3', [ 'id' => $id ]));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I done that like you commented and it works. Tnx!